# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.threeten.bp.LocalTime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-cloud

I have this gradle configuration:

***gradle***

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.10'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'
    implementation 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'javax.validation:validation-api'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    // Lombook
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    // Mapstruct
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.4.2.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.4.2.Final'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

***application.yml configuration***

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /api
logging:
  file:
    name: ${java.io.tmpdir}/application.log
  level:
    com:
      backend: DEBUG
    org:
      springframework: DEBUG
      springframework.web: DEBUG
spring:
  application:
    name: merchant-hub-admin-service
  profiles:
    active: dev
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        one-indexed-parameters: true # Fix pagination starting number to start from 1
    rest:
      basePath: /engine
  jackson:
    default-property-inclusion: non_null
  jmx:
    enabled: false
  datasource:
    platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
    url: jdbc:postgresql://test:5432/test
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: test
    password: test
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    database: postgresql
info:
  build:
    version: 1.0
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 5000
        readTimeout: 5000
        loggerLevel: basic
```

When I start the application I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.threeten.bp.LocalTime not present
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1318)
        at org.MerchantAdminApplication.main(MerchantAdminApplication.java:22)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.threeten.bp.LocalTime not present
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1156)
        at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._resolveSuperInterfaces(TypeResolver.java:444)
        at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._constructType(TypeResolver.java:439)
        at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver._fromClass(TypeResolver.java:387)
        at com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver.resolve(TypeResolver.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.convert.internal.AbstractConverterDescriptor.<init>(AbstractConverterDescriptor.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.convert.internal.ClassBasedConverterDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedConverterDescriptor.java:25)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addAttributeConverter(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:401)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl$AttributeConverterManager.addAttributeConverter(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:346)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.categorizeAnnotatedClass(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.threeten.bp.LocalTime
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
        ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the dependency for that type.
Just add this to your gradle file

```
implementation 'org.threeten:threetenbp:0.7.2'
```

Comment: Strange. I have the same project in Maven. Why I need here this dependency?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Maybe you have the dependency on that project but forgot to import here.